# trying to build trigger.io module get an error

Tags: android, module, trigger.io

I wanted to try and do some work with a module in trigger.io but seem to be running into some issues and the docs are well, not very good..

Anyhow I followed the step, the ones that were there anyhow and when I tried to run the project I'm getting an error message stateing

```
Running tests
Test running started
Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{io.trigger.forge.android.inspector/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
Empty test suite.
```

I did not change anything just tried to import and run but no matter what I do I cant get it to work. Have looked all around but found nothing that would work so any help would be nice